# Criteria Build Join ManyToMany Relation

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I need to relate 2 diferent entitys in a criteria build: ServiceBoat and ContractDocument. And for manytoMany reasons I created a third entity: ContractDocumentService with has 3 fields: id, serviceBoat and contractDocument.

But I can't seen to create a correct join for the criteria build:

```
        Root<ServiceBoat> rootServiceBoat;
        Join<ServiceBoat, ContractDocumentServiceModel> joinServiceBoatWithContractDocumentServiceModel;
        Join<ContractDocumentServiceModel, ContractDocument > joinContractDocumentServiceModelWithContractDocument;
        rootServiceBoat = criteria.from(ServiceBoat.class);
        joinServiceBoatWithContractDocumentServiceModel = rootServiceBoat.join("id", JoinType.INNER);
        joinContractDocumentServiceModelWithContractDocument = joinServiceBoatWithContractDocumentServiceModel.join("contractDocument", JoinType.INNER);
```

But It's giving me

> Cannot join to attribute of basic type

I know it's about me using the "id" attribute, but I don't know how to join this ContractDocumentService with the two other entities...

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the JavaDoc of the JPA Criteria API, you will understand that the various `join` methods can only be used to join associations. What you want to achieve here, creating entity joins, is not possible with the standard JPA Criteria API, not with JPQL.

Hibernate luckily supports entity joins though in HQL as of 5.1 and in a JPA Criteria extension as of 6.0.

Since you want to create inner joins though, you can use simple roots and model the join conditions as where clause predicates, as that is equivalent.

```
Root<ServiceBoat> rootServiceBoat;
Root<ContractDocumentServiceModel> rootServiceBoatWithContractDocumentServiceModel;
Root<ContractDocument> joinContractDocumentServiceModelWithContractDocument;
rootServiceBoat = criteria.from(ServiceBoat.class);
rootServiceBoatWithContractDocumentServiceModel = rootServiceBoat.from(ContractDocumentServiceModel.class);
joinContractDocumentServiceModelWithContractDocument = joinServiceBoatWithContractDocumentServiceModel.join("contractDocument", JoinType.INNER);

criteria.where(
  builder.equal(
    rootServiceBoat.get("id"),
    rootServiceBoatWithContractDocumentServiceModel.get("id")
  )
);
```